# problem with "title" in UINavigationController 

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, title

I am having a problem with title and UINavigationController. I am using the following code at UIViewControllerCurrent and when I get back from NextViewController, the title of the NavBar is still "Previous" ..Can anyone kindly help me out with this problem ? Thanks.

```
[self setTitle:@"Previous"]; 
NextViewController *controller = [[NextViewController alloc] init]; 
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
[controller release], controller = nil; 

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {     
[self setTitle:@"Real Title"];     
[super viewWillAppear:animated]; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to exchange the two lines

```
[self setTitle:@"Real Title"];     
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

so that you get

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self setTitle:@"Real Title"];
```

and I would put these into viewDidAppear.

Comment: if I put those inside viewWillAppear, it happens seamlessly, otherwise (atleast in the simulator) you notice the title changing. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UINavigationController delegate methods below.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Use one of the delegate method to change title.

Answer (score 0):

If dasdoms solution is not working the try the following.

In the NextViewController just before poping out run this code.

```
for (int i =0; i < [[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]; i++)
    {
        UIViewController *aController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([aController isKindOfClass:[PreviousViewController class]])
        {
            PreviousViewController *aPreviousViewController = (PreviousViewController *)aController;
            aPreviousViewController.title = @" Real Title";
        }

    }
```